# Multiple ACTIONS for a CASE to perform

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to perform 3 different actions in a CASE statement based on a single value from a table.
 1. Set a local variable for use in a multi-part project tracking number.
 2. Set a 2nd local variable for use in a different part of a multi-part project tracking number.
 3. Increment a counter for part 2.

```
DECLARE @location char(1) = 'P';
DECLARE @fundSource char(4) = 'SPRO';
DECLARE @fy char(2) = '19';
DECLARE @type char(2) = '';
DECLARE @loc_tn char(6) = '000000';
DECLARE @BR_i int = 1;
DECLARE @AR_i int = 0;

    SELECT @type = 
        CASE 
            WHEN proposalTypeID IN (1, 6) THEN 'BR'
            WHEN proposalTypeID IN (2, 7) THEN 'AR'
        END
    SELECT @loc_tn = 
        CASE
            WHEN proposalTypeID IN (1, 6) THEN right('000000' + cast(@BR_i+1 as varchar(6)), 6)
            WHEN proposalTypeID IN (2, 7) THEN right('000000' + cast(@AR_i+1 as varchar(6)), 6)
        END
    FROM proposalPackage WHERE proposalPackageID IN (17)

    DECLARE @trackingNumber char(20) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@location + '-' + @fundSource + '-' +  @type + '-' + @fy + '-' +  @loc_tn))
    SELECT @trackingNumber
```

I can comment out either of the CASE statements and the query runs fine.  When I try to keep them both in the query, I get an error "Invalid column name proposalTypeID" for the FIRST CASE Statement.

I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking but everywhere I look seems to show this to be the correct syntax.  And I can't find any reason that I can't use the same field in a subsequent CASE statement.

HELP??

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the second `select` with a comma:

```
SELECT @type = 
    CASE 
        WHEN proposalTypeID IN (1, 6) THEN 'BR'
        WHEN proposalTypeID IN (2, 7) THEN 'AR'
    END
, @loc_tn = 
    CASE
        WHEN proposalTypeID IN (1, 6) THEN right('000000' + cast(@BR_i+1 as varchar(6)), 6)
        WHEN proposalTypeID IN (2, 7) THEN right('000000' + cast(@AR_i+1 as varchar(6)), 6)
    END
FROM proposalPackage WHERE proposalPackageID IN (17)
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that freaking simple... thanks.